# I'm Having Trouble checking two values are equal in python

Tags: python

```
finishgame = "n"
counter = 0
#the song randomizer
num = random.randint(0,50)
f = open("songs.txt","r")
lines = f.readlines()
#first letter only system
song = str(lines[num])
firstl = song[0]
print(firstl)
#the artist generator
g = open("artists.txt","r")
line = g.readlines()
print(line[num])
#guess system
while finishgame == "n":
    guess = str(input("Enter your guess"))
    if guess == song:
        counter = counter+5
        print("Correct!")
        finishgame = "y"
    elif counter == 2:
        print("Out of guesses, sorry :(")
        print("The Correct Answer was:",song)
        finishgame = "y"
    else:
        counter = counter+1
        print("Try Again")
```

First time asking so apologizes for any errors. I have create a song guessing game where it takes a song from an external file, and displays the first letter of the title. It then takes the artist from a separate file (where it is in the same line as the song in the other file) and displays that too. Then you should guess the song. However, my code is having trouble recognizing when a 'guess' is correct, please can anyone tell me why? I've tried using different methods of identification such as the id() function but so far have not got any results. I'm probably missing something simple but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try using `if guess == song.strip()` instead of just `if guess == song` and see if it works

Comment: This is most likely because `readlines()` keeps the newline on the end of the string. You probably want to call `song.rstrip('\n')` to strip the trailing newline before comparing to the guess. Then you can also decide what to do about other whitespace in the answer and the guess, and maybe `.lower()` both to allow for capitalization, etc.

Comment: this might be due to casing, try using guess.lower() == song.lower()

it would also be useful to see a snippet of your input files